# Is there a more concise way of running this SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm joining two tables. One which contains records, and another which contains stats for those records. Here are my tables.

```
// ITEMS
item_id INT,
item_name NVARCHAR(MAX),
user_id INT

// STATS
stat_id INT,
item_id INT,
type TINYINT,
actions INT
```

Let's say I have two types of stat - views and edits. I want to return data in the following form

```
item_id   item_name   item_views   item_edits
1         thing       26           32
```

At the moment, the best way I can find to do this is by parsing my stat data into a temporary table and joining it to my item data. Actually, I'm putting both in table variables so I don't do any joins on live tables, to avoid any performance hit. Here's how it looks

```
DECLARE @i TABLE (item_id INT, item_name NVARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @s TABLE (item_id INT, item_views INT, item_edits);

INSERT INTO @i
SELECT item_id, item_name FROM Items WHERE user_id = 12345;

INSERT INTO @s
SELECT item_id,SUM(item_views),SUM(item_edits) FROM (
  SELECT item_id,
    item_views = CASE ISNULL(type,0) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(actions) ELSE 0 END,
    item_edits = CASE ISNULL(type,0) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(actions) END
  FROM Stats 
  WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM @i)
  GROUP BY item_id,stat_type
) as [x] 
GROUP BY item_id

SELECT 
  t.item_id,item_name,item_views,item_edits 
FROM @i t 
INNER JOIN @s s on s.item_id = t.item_id
```

It seems like there must be a simpler way to join things than this?

## EDIT:

Without the table variables, it would look (I believe) something like this

```
SELECT 
  t.item_id,item_name,item_views,item_edits 
FROM Items t 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT item_id,SUM(item_views),SUM(item_edits) FROM (
  SELECT item_id,
    item_views = CASE ISNULL(type,0) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(actions) ELSE 0 END,
    item_edits = CASE ISNULL(type,0) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(actions) END
  FROM Stats 
  WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE user_id = 12345)
  GROUP BY item_id,stat_type
) as [x] 
GROUP BY item_id
) as [s] 
ON s.item_id = t.item_id
WHERE user_id = @user_id
```

It still seems needlessly complex. It's got three subqueries. Is there a way I can group the stat rows using only case statements?

Comment: Yes, there is a simpler way. Eliminate the table variables (you're not using temp tables, you're using variables -- big difference)  and join/query the tables directly.  Let SQL Server handle the logistics of what is best to store on disk vs. in memory. That is what a DB system is for.

Comment: oops, I meant table variables.

Comment: your stat_type is 0 or 1 or null and if its null its 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it:

```
SELECT  t.item_id,t.item_name, 
        SUM(CASE ISNULL(s.[type],0) WHEN 0 THEN s.actions END) AS item_views,
        SUM(CASE s.[type] WHEN 1 THEN s.actions END) AS item_edits
FROM    Items t 
        LEFT JOIN [Stats] s ON t.item_id = s.item_id
WHERE   t.[user_id] = @user_id
GROUP BY t.item_id,t.item_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of unnecessary code. Try this:

```
SELECT t.item_id, t.item_name, iv.item_views, ie.item_edits 
FROM Items t 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(actions) AS item_views FROM STATS s WHERE s.item_id = t.item_id AND ISNULL(type, 0) = 0) iv
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(actions) AS item_edits FROM STATS s WHERE s.item_id = t.item_id AND ISNULL(type, 0) = 1) ie
```